# Sprite with userInteractionEnabled set to YES does not receive touches when covered by normal sprites

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I put a sprite A (subclassed to receive hits (userInteractionEnabled to YES)), and then a normal sprite B that does not take hits on top of that (userInteractionEnabled default NO), completely covering sprite A.

Tapping on sprite B, I assume that sprite A would get the touch but nothing happens. The part from docs about the matter is below.

I feel something is unclear here because it seems still that sprite B receives the touch but throws it away. <s>OR, spriteA is removed from possible touch receiver because it's not visible.</s>

From the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW7

> For a node to be considered during hit-testing, its
>   userInteractionEnabled property must be set to YES. The default value
>   is NO for any node except a scene node. A node that wants to receive
>   events needs to implement the appropriate responder methods from its
>   parent class (UIResponder on iOS and NSResponder on OS X). This is one
>   of the few places where you must implement platform-specific code in
>   Sprite Kit

Anyway to fix this?
As long as something's userInteractionEnabled is NO, it shouldn't interfere with other touch receivers.

Update: Even setting sprite B's alpha to 0.2, making sprite A very visible, will not make sprite A touchable. Sprite B just totally "swallows" the touch, despite being not enabled for interaction.

Comment: I have the same problem. The problem even exists if the the covering sprite has hidden = YES. It has to be a bug. Same thing if I create just a single touchable SKSpriteNode in the scene and then make it hidden = YES, it will still receive touches. Im thinking about filing a bug report to Apple but my last one havent even gotten any response at all so Im not that stoked about it.

Comment: I definitely think you should file the bug report. I have filed only a few in my days. Most of them were closed as duplicates, but for the record they fixed one of them (orientation issue with iPads, should be fixed since iOS5;^) ). Sure the response to the bug reports could take months or even more but it should still be worth it because this won't change by itself.

Comment: True that. I will file it. Thanks for the inspiration! the annoying thing is with bugs in SpriteKit compared to using Cocos2D is that fixing something in a new SpriteKit version creates a new requirement on the user to have the latest version of the OS.... instead of just including it in new version of the app.

Comment: Yes. And with cocos2d you can edit the source anytime to fit your needs. The strength of open source. You just can't do that with Sprite Kit. All you can do is file bug reports, or do ugly workarounds. This is where I think cocos2d should emphasize at this point: openness and fast bug fixing, platform compatibility (beyond Apple). Because sure, Sprite Kit will be big from now on.

Comment: @[johny](http://stackoverflow.com/users/129202/jonny) Did you get any proper solution for it??

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 8

Comment: Still not fixed, same problem here. This is unacceptable. This has apparently been an issue for what will be 2 years in a couple monthes

Comment: You could just check if the node is hidden in the same place you check if it was touched.  If it is, ignore the touch.  This is a lame workaround but it is quite easy.

Comment: Given that it's not "fixed" in iOS9.2.1, I would guess they no longer intend to fix it. @bobmoff Is the bug you filed still outstanding or has it been closed?

Answer (score 10):

Here is my solution until Apple updates SpriteKit with correct behaviour, or someone acctually figures out how to use it like we want.

https://gist.github.com/bobmoff/7110052

Add the file to your project and import it in your Prefix header. Now touches should work the way intended.

Comment: Cool, will definitely check it out later. I was porting a cocos2d game and on this occasion I did an ugly workaround, putting new temporary buttons (call them sprite-button Cs if you will) looking like sprite B on top of sprite B. I guess we can agree that the behaviour of SpriteKit is incorrect here, if I remember correctly non-interactable views in UIView does not block below below buttons, so there is an inconsistency there as well. In any case, this should go into the bug reports...

Comment: I took a look at your solution and I am  not quite sure how to use it. Could you provide a few sentences worth of how-to? Thanks :)

Comment: The solution extends both SKScene and SKNode, so there's nothing more you need to do to make it work. Just make sure that you import the file into either the top of your scene header file, or if you want to use it in all your scenes #import it in your prefix header file which is called ProjectName-Prefix.pch and is contained insides the "Supporting Files" folder.

Comment: i encountered exactly this issue. an sklabelnode was covering a button (though the text wasn't really covering the button and i'm still unsure how the frame for the sklabelnode is determined). adding the TouchPriority.m and TouchPriority.h to the project is sufficient. you do not need to add them to your pch file. thanks bobmoff!

Comment: I'd thought I'd elaborate a bit on how this works. Since the overlapping sprite prevents the targeted sprite from receiving touches (but doesn't accept touches itself), the touches are forwarded to the lowest parent node which does accept touches. If that's the SKScene, the category methods as described in this answer traverse the node tree down again and find the appropriate node according to its own selection procedure, which is what you want. Nice solution, helped me out (tested in iOS 9.0 public beta 1).

Comment: @bobmoff, thank you very much, it works! Swift version: https://gist.github.com/zmeyc/58d4c661ff3bb0d35db8   The workaround is no longer needed in iOS 9.

Comment: @Zmey I'm still seeing this in iOS 9.2.1.

Comment: Here's a working Swift solution https://gist.github.com/brynbodayle/46a6baeb575070f6e9bfc48371c74d23

Answer (score 2):

My solution doesn't require isKindOfClass sort of things...

In your SKScene interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKNode*   touchTargetNode;
// this will be the target node for touchesCancelled, touchesMoved, touchesEnded
```

In your SKScene implementation

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch*    touch   = [touches anyObject];
    NSArray*    nodes   = [self nodesAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];

    self.touchTargetNode = nil;

    for( SKNode* node in [nodes reverseObjectEnumerator] )
    {
        if( [node conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CSTouchableNode)] )
        {
            SKNode<CSTouchableNode>*    touchable   = (SKNode<CSTouchableNode>*)node;

            if( touchable.wantsTouchEvents )
            {
                self.touchTargetNode = node;
                [node touchesBegan:touches
                         withEvent:event];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.touchTargetNode touchesCancelled:touches
                                 withEvent:event];
    self.touchTargetNode = nil;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.touchTargetNode touchesMoved:touches
                             withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.touchTargetNode touchesEnded:touches
                                 withEvent:event];
    self.touchTargetNode = nil;
}
```

You will need to define the CSTouchableNode protocol... call it what you wish :)

```
@protocol CSTouchableNode <NSObject>

- (BOOL) wantsTouchEvents;
- (void) setWantsTouchEvents:(BOOL)wantsTouchEvents;

@end
```

For your SKNodes that you want to be touchable, they need to conform to the CSTouchableNode protocol. You will need to add something like below to your classes as required.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL wantsTouchEvents;
```

Doing this, tapping on nodes works as I would expect it to work. And it shouldn't break when Apple fixes the "userInteractionEnabled" bug. And yes, it is a bug. A dumb bug. Silly Apple.

**Updated**

There is another bug in SpriteKit... the z order of nodes is weird. I have seen strange orderings of nodes... thus I tend to force a zPosition for nodes/scenes that need it.

I've updated my SKScene implementation to sorting the nodes based on zPosition.

```
nodes = [nodes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"zPosition" ascending:false]]];
for( SKNode* node in nodes )
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for getting touches etc..

**The Scene**

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        HeroSprite *newHero = [HeroSprite new];
        newHero.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        [self addChild:newHero];

        SKSpriteNode *overLapSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor orangeColor] size:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];
        overLapSprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 30, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        overLapSprite.name = @"overlap";
        [self addChild:overLapSprite];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"heroNode"]) {
        NSLog(@"Scene detect hit on hero");
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"overlap"]) {
        NSLog(@"overlap detect hit");
    }

    // go through all the nodes at the point
    NSArray *allNodes = [self nodesAtPoint:location];
    for (SKNode *aNode in allNodes) {
        NSLog(@"Loop; node name = %@", aNode.name);
    }
}
```

**The Subclassed sprite / Hero**

```
- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setUpHeroDetails];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setUpHeroDetails
{
    self.name = @"heroNode";
    SKSpriteNode *heroImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    [self addChild:heroImage];
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint locationA = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint locationB = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];
    NSLog(@"Hero got Hit at, %@ %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(locationA), NSStringFromCGPoint(locationB));
}

@end
```

Tried many things, but the touch doesn't go through the overlapping sprite. I guess you can use the scene class to detect the touch via looping through the nodes then directly call that node.

I had this problem when a particle emitter covered a button...

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Overlapping nodes are getting the touches in their place in the zOrder. Higher position gets first, then all the below ones. From here just one step to filter which object would you like to receive the touch and refuse the touch event for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a design choice, but certainly not very flexible. I prefer to handle objects that can overlap (like game objects) in Sprite Kit at Scene level with nodeAtPoint: combined with isKindOfClass: methods. For objects like buttons that usually do not overlap and  are placed in a different layer (like overlays and buttons), I handle their user interaction inside their classes.
I would like my touch events to "bubble up" the nodes tree as it happens in Sparrow Framework, but i fear it is more a feature request than a bug report.

P.S.: By handling touches at scene level you can easily touch and move nodes even if they are completely covered by non-movable and non-touchable nodes!

Comment: I don't think it's a design choice, or the docs are plain incorrect "For a node to be considered during hit-testing, its userInteractionEnabled property must be set to YES. The default value is NO for any node except a scene node. "

Do you handle buttons this way as well, including highlighting?

Comment: Uhm, I think your're right, I didn't read it accurately. I organize my scene basically on two main layers, game layer (first to be added) and overlay (on top). Given that buttons will not overlap one another, i handle their interaction inside the button class. I'm developing just for iOS then I never used highlighting, but I think i would do the same way.

Comment: I spoke to the Apple team at the iOS Tech Talk in Berlin and explained thi problems, and they said it is probably a bug as I wasn't the only one reporting this and the behaviour doesn't work the way the documentation states.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with fewer lines of code. Remember to set userInteractionEnabled in every node you want to receive touch.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint touchLocation = self.positionInScene;
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

    NSArray *nodes   = [self nodesAtPoint:touchLocation];
    for (SKSpriteNode *node in [nodes reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        NSLog(@"Node in touch array: %@. Touch enabled: %hhd", node.name, node.isUserInteractionEnabled);
        if (node.isUserInteractionEnabled == 1)
            touchedNode = node;
    }
    NSLog(@"Newly selected node: %@", touchedNode);
}
```