# Objective C - SKNode subclass to 'swallow' touches?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

I am trying to subclass an `SKNode` so that when you touch **its frame (the minimum frame to enclose its children)**, it is notified by the `touchesBegan::` method.

However, it seems that it will only be notified if a `SKSpriteNode` child is touched. I have tried overriding the `containsPoint:` method but with no success.

Here is my code:

```
@interface gameNode : SKNode {
    SKSpriteNode* mainChar;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <gameNodeDelegate> delegate;

@end

@implementation gameNode // When touched, touchesBegan: method not getting called.

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        mainChar = [SKSpriteNode node]; // When touched, touchesBegan: method gets called.
        mainChar.color = [SKColor redColor];
        mainChar.size = CGSizeMake(25, 25);
        [mainChar runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:0 duration:0]];
        mainChar.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        [self addChild:mainChar];

        SKSpriteNode* n = [SKSpriteNode node]; // When touched, touchesBegan: method gets called.
        n.size = mainChar.size;
        n.position = CGPointMake(-100, -100);
        n.color = [SKColor greenColor];
        [self addChild:n];

        [mainChar runAction:[SKAction customAnimationWithProperties:CUAPropertiesForScaleBounce(CUADirectionTypeIn, 1)]];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"That's a touch!");
}

-(void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

@end
```

What happens is I only get a touch event when the mainChar and n `SKSpriteNodes` nodes are touched and not the rest of the screen.

The only way I could think to get it to work is to add a transparent `SKSpriteNode` to the background, but there must be a better way!

How can I make it so the `SKNode` 'swallows' the touches it receives, regardless of whether a child is being child is being touched? **i.e I want touches in the `SKNodes`'s frame to notifiy it via the `touchesBegan::` method.**

**Update:** I think this is a problem with the `SKNode`'s frame. When I do after adding the children..

```
NSLog(@"Frame Width: %f, Frame Height: %f", self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
```

The frame is returned as having a height and width of 0. However, when I do `[self calculateAccumulatedFrame]`, it returns the correct size. Why is this?

**Update:** This question is a complete mess. I am just going to stick with the solution of adding a transparent `SKSpriteNode` or using an `SKScene`. Sorry for the bafflement everyone, I appreciate your help.

Comment: That's not how you enable user interaction. `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` is the correct way.

Comment: You shouldn't override it. It might mess with the `UIResponder` system, and that's probably why you don't receive touches.

Comment: I've just tested and it works the same with either, but I do understand I should've done it through the setter, I've updated the OP.

Comment: Works either way? But your post is about the node *not* detecting touches?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it _does_ work with children either way but it still _doesn't work_ with the `SKNode` itself either way. **Edit:** Actually I said 'works the same', which it does! I get the same results from both.

Comment: Another thing. Read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:) for `UIResponder`. If you override `touchesBegan:`, you'd have to override the other 3 methods too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sprite with userInteractionEnabled set to YES does not receive touches when covered by normal sprites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511334/sprite-with-userinteractionenabled-set-to-yes-does-not-receive-touches-when-cove)

Comment: @duci9y The overriding of the other 3 methods shouldn't affect the `touchesBegan:` method from not being called, although it may cause other problems. However, I have tested with the changes and it still doesn't work as intended. I have updated the OP.

Comment: @ddr2 Although that question is very ambiguous as it doesn't refer to which component of SpriteKit it is referring to, I am assuming it's referring not to `SKNode` but instead `SKSpriteNode`, which I am aware has the issue of swallowing touches irrespective of its `userInteractionEnabled` state. This isn't the problem I'm having though, I **want** touch swallowing!

Comment: hum ... I think I am lost :) What I understand is that your `SKNode`'s `touchesBegans` isn't called even though it has `userInteractionEnabled`, how is that any different from the situation in the question I pointed to ? With a child, the event do not "bubble up" and that's pretty much it ? Have you tried without any child node to see if your `touchesBegans` get called ?

Comment: I suggest you clarify your question, so it is perfectly clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally posted that comment before finishing it :P It's different to the other question as there is nothing covering the `SKNode`, therefore nothing swallowing the touches. I have tried removing children and still doesn't work as intended. It's also not an `SKSpriteNode`, which has a defined size, whether `SKNode` handles its size differently, therefore making me think that it could have issues with touches that `SKSpriteNodes` don't.

Comment: "I have tried removing children and still doesn't work as intended." Are you getting the touches when you have no child ? That's basically the first problem you need to fix before even trying to "swallow" them I think

Comment: @ddr2 No, I am getting no touch notifications when there are no children. To clarify: I **only** receive touch notifications on this `SKNode` when a child is tapped and not anywhere else on the screen.

Comment: You cannot do this, an `SKNode` doesn't have definite bounds in which it will detect touches. Use your scene to detect touches 'anywhere on the screen'.

Comment: @duci9y I thought it had a frame that was the minimum size to enclose its children?

Comment: That's a computed property. It does not have an intrinsic size. Seriously, just use an `SKScene`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `SKNode` doesn't have any intrinsic bounds. It does not perform any drawing, and you can effectively think of it not being rendered on the screen either. **It will not detect touches.**

The functionality you are looking for is best provided by an `SKScene`. Use an `SKScene`.

Comment: Is it correct practice to add an `SKScene` to another `SKScene`?

Comment: @originaluser2 That'll work, but you better use an `SKSpriteNode` instead.

Comment: That's what I was going to do, but didn't want the extra baggage that `SKSpriteNode`s bring! Nevertheless, this seems like the best solution. Thanks for your help, I apologise for original confusing question.

Comment: @originaluser2 The 'extra baggage' `SKSpriteNode` brings includes proper touch handling. And really, that's all it brings. There's no 'extra baggage' at all, seriously.

Comment: Ok. I just wish the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) was clearer as it states that "All nodes are responder objects that can respond directly to user interaction with the node onscreen."