# Xcode 7.2, iOS 8.X, SpriteKit, Sprite do not recognize any touch

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, touch, ios-simulator

I have developed:

- Game in Swift 2.1.1 (current version) and SpriteKit
- I'm running on Xcode 7.2
- OS X 10.11.2 (EL Capitan)
- Game project setting 'deployment target' is set to 8.0.

Everything is OK on real iPhone 6 device and any simulator running on iOS 9.x.

But I need to test it on iOS 8.x, I have only simulator with this version. Game starts correctly - everything looks fine, but I'm unable to click anywhere. Click / touch is not recognized. No error in log or Xcode. I do not know what is wrong, simulator or my game.

Does anyone have a similar issue? Thanks for advice.

**EDIT:**
After some research, I find that iOS 8 have bug: one (allscreen) sprite with property hidden=true is over my touchable sprite - button. This allscreen sprite 'absorb' all touches. Even if it is hidden. This bug is fixed in iOS 9.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: I find same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511334/sprite-with-userinteractionenabled-set-to-yes-does-not-receive-touches-when-cove but without any simple fix

Answer (score 0):

My workaround: Do not only hide, but remove from parent sprite too.
All my sprites are descendants of MySpriteNode. In that class I implement function setVisible(), implementation:

```
func setVisible(visible:Bool, _ newParent:SKNode?)
{
    // hide sprite
    if !visible
    {
        self.hidden = true
        self.removeFromParent()
    }

    // show sprite
    else
    {
        self.hidden = false
        if newParent != nil && self.parent == nil
        {
            newParent!.addChild(self)
        }
        else
        {
            // Sprite is visible (with old parent)
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to hide sprite:

```
myButton.setVisible(false, nil)
```

If I want to show sprite, I must know a parent:

```
myButton.setVisible(true, self)
```

Now, touches are recognized successfully.